# Dectect motion with RFID without use of sensors

Tags: rfid, motion-detection

Does anyone know if the use of only one static active RFID tag are able to detect motion(eg. moving human or objects) by itself without any use of other extra tags or sensors?

Comment: Did you find out the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could be able to do it by doing a permanent inventory and getting both the time and the signal strength received from the tag in each session. Both will be an indication that either orientation or distance has changed, but they are not exclusivelly corelated (you could have a change of both factors even if the tag is not moving) so you should do extensive test before settling on the solution.
Since you are talking about an active tag, there are manufacturers that incorporate motion sensors into their tag in order to save battery (tag emits more often when its moving), so you should contact them to see which of them can allow you to gather data from the sensor.
If you are thinking about fixing the tag on a wall and have the tag detect when someone passes by it, I do not know that such a product exist: there are tags that have thermometers or even humidity sensors integrated but not area of interest motion detection, for this you can use a wireless motion sensor.